# How to make CSS Grid columns span 12 columns by default

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to edit my `.grid` class so that writing this will span 12 by default?

```
<div class="grid">
    <div>col</div> <!-- I want this to span-12 by default -->
</div>
```

Here is my `.grid` class:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}
```

I know how to do it *manually*, but is it possible to modify my `.grid` to make it implicit with 12 equal columns?

```
<div class="grid">
    <div style="grid-column:auto / span 12">col</div>
    <div style="grid-column:1 / -1">col</div>
</div>
```

I've been staring at [grid-auto-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns) for an hour now, trying a bunch of different things with no luck yet.

Comment: *is it possible to modify my .grid to make it implicit?* --> no you cannot

Comment: Thanks. `.grid > * { grid-column: 1 / -1 }`

Comment: ^ you are not editing ".grid" by doing this

Comment: After reading you post, I am confused, inside the grid you want only one child `div` but 12 columns ? Is this related to items placement, you want to store in your grid between 1 and 12 child divs ?

Comment: @BenSouchet By default I want all new children of my `.grid` container to span 12 columns. I don't think it's possible without positioning hacks, which I'm strongly against in my code. My grid needs 12 explicit columns, so I'm going to have to specify the default span for children outside of my `.grid` container somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, I think you are looking to do something like that:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  background-color: grey;
}
.col {
  grid-column: span 12;
}
.a {
  background-color: blue;
}
.b {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col a">1</div> 
  <div class="col b">2</div>
</div>
```

Tell me if this is what you was looking for :)